# Regular expression pattern to distinguish these texts

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the below text, and I want a regular expression pattern for it:

```
qos policy 1024SharedUnlimitedUserRX pwfq 
rate maximum 1792
weight 16
num-queues 4
queue-map Fastweb
congestion-map Fastweb
queue 0 priority 0 weight 100
queue 1 priority 1 weight 90
queue 2 priority 2 weight 70
queue 3 priority 3 weight 85
```

The pattern should fetch the integer value after the first `weight` phrase. In other words I want the 16 value, but not value of the next 4 lines(100, 90, 70, 85).

I wrote this pattern:

```
/weight (\d*)/
```

but this pattern found value of the other lines too, what should I do?

Note: I used `preg_math()` function, not `preg_match_all()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex would perhaps suit you:

```
preg_match('/^weight (\d+)/m', $input, $match);
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/sG6aF2)

`^` makes sure that the `weight` is at the beginning of the line.

The `m` flag makes `^` match at the beginning of each line instead of only at the beginning of the string.

If there can be other `weight` you don't want which can be at the beginning of the line, you can try this instead, which makes sure that the `weight` is just after `maximum`:

```
preg_match('/maximum \S*\s*weight (\d+)/m', $input, $match);
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/aG2vJ8)

Comment: Good answer, because you explain it and don't just throw it in.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
  <?php
    $input_line="qos policy 1024SharedUnlimitedUserRX pwfq 
    rate maximum 1792
    weight 16
    num-queues 4
    queue-map Fastweb
    congestion-map Fastweb
    queue 0 priority 0 weight 100
    queue 1 priority 1 weight 90
    queue 2 priority 2 weight 70
    queue 3 priority 3 weight 85";

preg_match("/(?:weight\s(\d+)(?!\S+))/", $input_line, $output_array);
print_r($output_array);
```

[**`DEMO`**](https://eval.in/109699)

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => weight 16
    [1] => 16
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
(?<=weight )\d+
```

Check the regex at http://regex101.com/r/eP2yS2

### DEMO

```
<?php
$input_line="qos policy 1024SharedUnlimitedUserRX pwfq 
rate maximum 1792
weight 16
num-queues 4
queue-map Fastweb
congestion-map Fastweb
queue 0 priority 0 weight 100
queue 1 priority 1 weight 90
queue 2 priority 2 weight 70
 queue 3 priority 3 weight 85";

preg_match("/(?<=weight )\d+/", $input_line, $output_array);

 print_r($output_array);
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 16
)
```

Link : https://eval.in/109758

Answer (score 0):

```
rate maximum \d+[\s\S]+?weight \d+
```